# If inside if or Send data from JavaScript function to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql

I'm newbie in JavaScript and I need to edit a file contains with JS code.

I have a table with actions button (some one had created it before, and I need to edit), look at the icon-pencil:

[image]

The code for that button is here:

```
<tr><td align=\"center\">$uname</td><td align=\"center\">$loc1</td><td align=\"center\">$dept</td><td align=\"center\">$date</td><td align=\"center\"><button class=\"btn btn-mini\"data-toggle=\"modal\"href=\"#long\"
onClick=\"javascript:edit('$name','$uname','$emid','$dob','$gender','$job','$info','$datejoin','$locid','$deptid','$myid','$templatelist','newbal');\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i></a>
```

The javascript:edit which called by that button is here:

```
function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
        document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k7; document.getElementById("frm").name.value=a;
        document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b;
        document.getElementById("frm").emid.value=c;
        document.getElementById("frm").dob.value=d;
        setCheckedValue(document.forms['frm'].elements['gender'],e);
        document.getElementById("frm").job.value=f;
        document.getElementById("frm").info.value=g;
        document.getElementById("frm").datejoin.value=h;
        document.getElementById('locid').value=i;
        document.getElementById('deptid').value=m m;

      var lapplicant = b; //added by me
      window.location.href = "http://192.168.1.5/eleave/employee.php?lapplicant=" + lapplicant; //added by me
        }
```

the code "added by me" is use for send b to php file. And I just used `$lapplicant = $_GET['lapplicant'];` in PHP file to get the data from the JS function.

Then `$lapplicant` is used for postgresql query and use the data from the query to get `$value`, here is the code:

```
$lapplicant = $_GET['lapplicant'];
$querye = "select leavetype.id, leavetype.ltype, leaves.leave from leavetype,leaves where username='".$_SESSION["username"]."'";
    
    $resulte = pg_query($querye); 
    
    while ($rowe = pg_fetch_array($resulte)) {

        $ct=$ct+1; //it will put on $llisting

        $lid = $rowe[id]; //it will put on $llisting

        $ltype = $rowe[ltype]; //it will put on $llisting

        $leave = $rowe[leave];  

    if ($lid == $ccompassionate) {
        $compassionate_query = pg_query("select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='".$lapplicant."' and ltype='".$ccompassionate."'");
        if (count($compassionate_query) > 0) {
            foreach ($compassionate_query as $data) {
                $total_compassionate = $total_compassionate + $data['total'];
                $value = $compassionate - $total_compassionate;
            }

        } else {
            $value = $compassionate;
        }

    } elseif ($lid == $cemergency) {
        $emergency_query = pg_query("select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='".$lapplicant."' and ltype='".$cemergency."'");
        if (count($emergency_query) > 0) {
            foreach ($emergency_query as $data) {
                $total_emergency = $total_emergency + $data['total'];
                $value = $emergency - $total_emergency;
            }

        } else {
            $value = $emergency;
        }
}

$llisting=$llisting."<tr><td align=\"center\">$ct</td><td>$ltype</td><td><input type='text' value='$value'></td><td align=\"center\">";

$llisting=$llisting."<select name=\"temp$lid\" id=\"temp$lid\" class=\"span12\"><option value=\"0\"> - </option> $tlisting</select>";

$llisting=$llisting."</td></tr>\n";
```

When I run the page, there aren't data show on the field:

[image]

And I got confuse, is the problem cause using wrong IF ELSE structure or using wrong send data from JS to PHP code? If you know the problem, could you tell me and give the solution?

Comment: First off: Have you made sure the data actually gets to the page? i.e. `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: Your query might be giving **username is ambiguous** error. Try leavetype.username or leave.username

Comment: I've tried to call $lapplicant on the table, Darren. And it doesn't appear. So, my problem is the JS to PHP. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think my query giving ambiguous, cause I've tried to execute in the database, Rajesh.